# thread safety when interacting with cache

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I have a question to assist with my understanding of thread safety and concurrency in my .net c# application.

To take for example, reading and writing from the asp.net cache.

I am developing a high scale .net application, with interaction with the cache.

I am aware of the different levels of concurrency, optimistic and pessimistic. However I am slightly confused what the difference between this and thread safety.

When interacting with the cache, should I be using locks to ensure that the cache does not get manipulated by multiple threads as its being read and written to. So should I be using locks? And how does this fit in with concurrency?

Comment: You are asking many questions at once.

Comment: I only see 1 main question: "should I be using locks ...". The rest is introduction.

Answer (score 4):

Optimistic and pessimistic concurrency are concepts used for handling updates by multiple users and preventing users to overwrite each others changes. They are used at another level than thread safety. Locking for thread safety is most similar to pessimistic concurrency.

The ASP.NET cache object itself is thread safe. You can access it from multiple threads without the collection itself being damages. However you are responsible yourself of ensuring thread safety for the objects that you do put in your cache.

The easiest approach is probably to make all objects that are to be put into the cache immutable (like e.g. .NET's `string` class). Once created the object will never be updated and only read from. Read-only operations are always thread safe. If you need to update the data you create a new object based on the old one and replaces the object in the cache. That way you won't have to deal with thread safety yourself as you can rely on the cache object for that.

If you have to update the objects in the cache, you have to make sure that all update operations of those objects are thread safe.

Comment: @Waht about if 2000 threads wants to read from cache ? One started reading. will the other 1999 are waiting ?

Answer (score 0):

In essence optimistic locking schemes are based on the idea that in normal operation writes to the same data will not be concurrent. So they have some sort of versioning mechansim so a potential collision can be detected and they throw an error. In Crud apps that's usually "someone else has changed this data please try again", and hopefully returning the current data so this can be done.

Pessimistic locking schemes assume that in normal operation the bulk of writes will be concurrent, so a lock is taken and no concurrent update can take place until the current write has completed. In a CRUD app that would be something like "User Fred has Customer Bill locked , please try again later.

Which ever locking mechanism you choose to implement it should still be thread safe, either a concurrent write can't happen or a concurrent write that would result in a data collision should fail.